# Por qué mi controlador no recibe mi parámetro en mi web ASP .NET MVC 5

Tags: c#, html5, asp.net-mvc-5, razor, controller

He estado queriendo hacer un filtro por nombre de usuario con "STARTSWITH" pero la vista no está captando mi valor, aunque tengo dudas ya que hace un momento probé usando "CONTAIN" en vez de STARTSWITH y me cogió. Pero no es lo que quiero para este caso.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
    @model IEnumerable

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "UsuarioXNombre";
}

<h2>UsuarioXNombre</h2>

<p>
    @using (Html.BeginForm("UsuarioXNombre","Usuario"))
    {
        <b>Ingrese el nombre:</b> <input type="text" name="nombre" value=@ViewBag.nombre />
        <input type="submit" value="Consultar" />
    }
</p>
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.USUARIO)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.PASSWORD)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.PERFIL)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.DNI)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.NOM_USU)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.TELEFONO)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.EMAIL)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.DIRECCION)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.FEC_REG)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.FEC_UPD)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.EST_USU)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.USUARIO)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PASSWORD)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PERFIL)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DNI)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.NOM_USU)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TELEFONO)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.EMAIL)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DIRECCION)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FEC_REG)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FEC_UPD)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.EST_USU)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ })
        </td>
    </tr>
}

</table>
```

Comment: Este workshop te será de utilidad hermano https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6LZG76aLykY :D bienvenido a SOes!

Comment: Por la imagen que pusiste se observa que **nombre** es *null*; prueba usando el **??** es decir **p.NOM_USU.StartsWith((nombre??""))** cuida antes de hacer busqueda en o usando valores *null* o desde un inicio "decide" que devolver en caso que *nombre* sea *null*.

Answer (score 0):

El problema esta en que no controlas el caso en que la variable nombre este vacia por eso te da ese error. prueba hacer esto

```
public ActionResult UsuarioXNombre(string nombre)
    {           
        var lista = from s in db.Usuarios select s;

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(nombre))
        {
           lista = lista.Where(s => s.Nombre.StartsWith(nombre));
        }
        return View(lista);
    }
```

otra cosa que no vi en tu codigo fue

```
@model IEnumerable<NombreDeTuApp.Models.Usuario>
```

esto debes pornerlo al principio de tu vista puesto que estas usando una vista fuertemente tipada a un modelo la cual espera una coleccion para mostrar, de otra forma deberias pasar entonces la lista en un ViewBag. En este ejemplo el controlador retorna la lista con todos los Usuarios en caso de no filtrar pero puedes modificar el controlador a tu gusto (sin eliminar el if que controla la Exception).Espero te sea de ayuda